# How to make url mappings like facebook do for all of its users and pages

Tags: java, facebook, jakarta-ee, servlets

I was just wondering, in java when we need to have something like `www.mydomain.com/buy` then I would make a servlet and map it to `buy` and add it to deployment descriptor. So for every such link I would have a servlet there which is specifically mapped to that name only.

But now facebook offers every user an independent url to his profile, like `www.facebook.com/user1` or `www.facebook.com/user2/friends`, I don't have much knowledge of php so I don't know how are they doing but I was wondering if somebody have to do same thing in java, then I don't think it is feasible to create mapping for 800 million users in deployment descriptor and creating same number of servlets for them.

Is there any way to make such thing possible in java?

And not only facebook many websites do it, like some very big ecommerce website I know show products like this `www.ecom.com/camera-nikon` or `www.ecom.com/nokia-n70-music-edition/`

Answer (score 0):

Such mapping has be done programmatically. You need `DispatcherServlet` mapped to `/*`. It will analyse URL, extract user name from it and perform appropriate calls inside your business logic.

BTW Spring MVC provides higher level mapping facilities. For example you can write controller mapped to `/` (as servlet mentioned above). The you can define method annotated as following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userName}/friends, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User[] getFriends(@PathVariable(value = "userName") String userName) {
....
}
```

The mapping between user name passed into URL and the method argument will be done automatically.

Comment: I also thought of same thing, but do you think this way is fast enough? Because both users(`www.facebook.com/user1`) and pages(`www.facebook.com/page1`) have same url, so basically they extract what is coming after `/` and search through their entire db of users and pages to find a match?